# Benefits of factoring a new class vs string values for elements in a Set

Tags: java

This is more of a design question with implications for code simplicity vs. performance.

Lets say you want to make sure a set of values for a given user id are the same between two systems. The example here is to check that a student id has the same number of course enrollments in System A and System B.

For this we create:

```
List<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> sysAEnrollments = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> sysBEnrollments = new HashSet<String>();
private Map<String, String> badEnrollList = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And fill them appropriately, given a list of student ids(studentList):

```
studentList = getCurrentStudentList();

for (String id : studentList){
   sysAEnrollments = getSysAEnrollments(id);
   sysBEnrollments = getSysBEnrollments(id);
   if (!sysAEnrollments.containsAll(sysBEnrollments)){
      badEnrollList.put(id, getBadEnrollmentsById(id, sysAEnrollments, sysBEnrollments));
   }
}
```

**Question:** What should the method '*getBadEnrollmentsById*' return?

Either a concatenated string with enough meaning so it can just be printed out.
Or have a new object, for example another collection with the list of course ids that could be used for further processing but harder to use for printed output.

Is it worth designing thoroughly all expected objects or replace some of them with concatenated strings for clarity and performance?

**NOTES:**

- System A is preferred as the authoritative source
- Output from *getBadEnrollmentsById* should have all courses and flag those missing in system B.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION: (2012-SEP-14)**

**EDIT (2012-SEP-17): Updated the Course class to include hashCode and equals**

As suggested by user351721 I continued modelling the remaining objects that match the expected results/requirements.
Slight changes made a big difference and allowed me to go over this design flaw and finish with the implementation.

The revised collections are:

```
List<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();
Enrollment sysAEnrollments;
Enrollment sysBEnrollments;
Map<String, List<String>> badEnrollList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

And we populate the Enrollments:

```
for (String id : studentList){
    sysAEnrollments = getSysAEnrollments(id);
    sysBEnrollments = getSysBEnrollments(id);
    if (!sysAEnrollments.getCourses().containsAll(sysBEnrollments.getCourses())){
        List<String> missingCourses = getProblemEnrollmentListById(id, sysAEnrollments, sysBEnrollments);
        badEnrollList.put(id, missingCourses);
    }
}
```

So for now the output can be printed from badEnrollList by getting at each ArrayList and printing the course names. A course name with a * will mean that it's missing in sysB.

The Enrollment class looks like this:

```
public class Enrollment {
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses){
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    public Set<Course> getCourses(){
        return this.courses;
    }
}
```

And the Course class ended up like this:

```
public class Course {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Must override hashCode() and equals()
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Course))
            return false;
        Course c = (Course) o;
        return c.id.equals(this.id) && c.name.equals(this.name);
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode(){
        // Magic numbers as shown on Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java" 2nd Edition, p.48
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * this.id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * this.name.hashCode();
        return result;
    }   
}
```

The changes might look subtle but the important clue is that Enrollments are not a collection of strings, Enrollments are a collection of Courses AND each Course has a name and a availability property. They don't seem to do much but by using them I am defining the objects that I'm working with and documenting how these classes can be reused in the future.

Comment: "What should the method 'getBadEnrollmentsById' return?" Well, what do you want to use it for? Are you printing to screen, doing manipulation of some student objects, enrolling them in system B, un-enrolling them from system A, etc...?

Comment: For now I just want to email the list of courses for each id. Output could look something like this:
`Student123456 MATH-101 BIO-301 ACCT-101*`
The course with * would be the one missing in sysB

Comment: What about classes in system B but missing in system A?

Comment: Classes in sysB and not in sysA would have to be purged. Good catch.

Comment: I think with a comparable object I don't have to worry about:
`Student123456 MATH-101 BIO-301` not being an equal string to `Student123456 BIO-301 MATH-101`

Comment: Have you considered inheriting from ArrayList? This way you could have the normal ArrayList functionality but you could override the ToString() method to keep the pretty output. Or did I miss the point of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests" addresses this question: chapter 7, "Value Types". Worth reading. An excerpt:

> The more code we write, the more we’re convinced that we should define types to represent value concepts in the domain, even if they don’t do much. It helps to create a consistent domain model that is more self-explanatory. If we create, for example, an Item type in a system, instead of just using String, we can f ind all the code that’s relevant for a change without having to chase through the method calls

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this design principle. I felt something was missing but wanted to see if it was common to use Strings. I've now mapped out the full object model for what is expected and I will try to implement it as thoroughly as I can. Basically what it's needed is an Enrollment pojo that contains a set of Course objects. The state of each course will say if it's available, missing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> concatenated strings

would mean you have to define a pattern and corresponding set of valid strings and implement validation and translation to entity classes. Providing an interface or class would make it easier to update your code in a year or so, not to mention other programmers that might work with your application. Why not store student, enrollment or course objects in `badEnrollList`? How do these objects look like and what do you want to do with them?

In general: Yes, designing thoroughly all expected objects is worth it.

Comment: Agreed, its the fear of being prepared for additional requests!
If I could have an enrollment object composed of course objects I could easily process what is the course with most issues with students or which students have all their courses missing for example. This saves us hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: +1 for "please God don't use strings here, use a bona fide object."

Answer (score 1):

I feel that a collection, such as `List<String>` would be a desirable return value.  This allows you to more efficiently capture multiple discrepancies between the two sets, and process the missing courses in your second object more intuitively.  Printing the list wouldn't be that hard, either - depending on how you wished to convey the information.

It's also worth mentioning that the `.equals()` method for `Set` is a cleaner and more intuitive way to ensure equivalence between two sets.

Comment: Agreed, I definitely need an ArrayList of BadEnrollment objects. Getting closer but don't know what a BadEnrollment object looks like yet.

Comment: I should say, an ArrayList of objects and each object has all the student courses for the current semester plus an additional property indicating which ones are missing in system B. I don't want to name that object to avoid confusing what it should be.

Comment: Just let `getBadEnrollmentsById` return the `List` of courses missing in system B then. No need for an additional property, only put the items you want in your return list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using all these sets and maps, I'd use Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs) that reflect the actual business objects in question. From what you've indicated, you have Students who have an id of some sort, and who are enrolled in classes on System A and on System B. I would build up a set of Student objects defined like so:

```
public class Student {
    private String id;
    private List<String> enrollmentsA;
    private List<String> enrollmentsB;

    // appropriate getters and setters
}
```

Depending on if you want to do anything else with Classes, it may even be preferable to create some form of EnrolledClass object to represent that too.

Within the students class, I'd then have a method that would determine the "bad" enrollments. If all that you want to do with this data is generate an email message, it may even be as simple as a String:

```
public String getBadEnrollmentsMessage() {
    List<String> enrolledBoth = getCommonEnrollments();
    List<String> enrolledOnlyA = getAOnlyEnrollments();
    List<String> enrolledOnlyB = getBOnlyEnrollments();

    StringBuilder output;
    // format the contents of the above lists into output
    // format should be however you want it in the email.

    return output.toString();
}
```

Then you could have a map of Students to email enrollments messages:

```
HashMap<Student, String> studentEmails;

for (Student s : allStudents) {
    studentEmails.put(s, s.getBadEnrollmentsMessage());
}
```

Of course, if you have a method like `getBadEnrollmentsMessage()`, I'm not even sure you need the Map of students and strings in the first place. Frankly you could just create a `sendEnrollmentEmail` method, pass in a `Student`, and extract the message via `getBadEnrollmentsMessage()` right there.

Comment: I don't want to drop maps and sets because they are part of the object domain. As suggested by 'user351721' I was missing the list of objects to put in those collections. I have now modeled an Enrollment class that should hold Course classes. Those enrollment objects are then put into the appropriate sets.